# Extjs item.el is undefined! How do I ensure my component has rendered so that others can call its element?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I've got a component, which extends from Ext.button.Button, and another component, wrappanel, which is responsible for laying out the custom button component.

My problem is, the wrappanel component calculates the width of the items being passed to it and requires `item.el` to be available. `item.el` is not available until the component has rendered, but rendering is deferred until all components are ready.

How can I ensure that my child component has its .el ready for use by the parent component? Thanks.

Comment: try with afterRender listener for child items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculating the width of child items is the responsibility of the layout manager, not the container. Depending on your version of Ext JS, however, writing a custom layout might be a tall order if you're not comfortable with the codebase.

If you're using 4.1.0 or later, take a look at [Ext.layout.Context](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.layout.Context) for the ultimate reference guide to the layout process. The 4.1 release marked a huge change to the layout system to address reports of performance issues, so the information there won't help you if you're using 4.0.7 or earlier.

The 4.1 layouts are much, *much* more difficult to wrap your head around (in my opinion), so I'd recommend trying to coax an existing layout to fill your requirements before trying to customize one. If you're 4.0.7 or earlier it's a bit easier, so you may have more flexibility there.

Comment: You are not the only one.  The layout context makes debugging layout issues very hard, since everything is queued it is hard to detect where the problem is actually occurring (`beginLayout`, `calculate`, `completeLayout`, `finalizeLayout` etc.).   There are also lots of confusing configs that one can not follow without understanding large chucks of Ext specific layout context knowledge.  Take a look at http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/source/AbstractComponent.html#Ext-AbstractComponent-method-getSizeModel and see if any of the code makes sense.